# Visual Studio Code. Problem with starting cpp Application

Tags: c++

So i want to start my progamm, but it doesn't work. it is an cpp file And im Using the C/C++ g++.exe Compiler. i also wrote in the Task.jason  -->

```
            "-g"
            "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\main.exe",
            "--std=c++14"
```

But it doesn't work. It shows this Error :

```
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ ./main.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./main.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
PS C:\Users\fabia\Documents\Uni\2 Semester\PAD\Imageneu>
```

Thanks in Advance for the Help

Comment: That means that main.exe is not in the current folder. You can verify this in your windows file explorer. Make sure you turn off the option to hide extensions for known types so that windows does not hide the .exe part from you.

Comment: Thank you very much !